# Retrieve env variables in Strapi plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, strapi

I develop a [Strapi local plugin](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugin-development/quick-start.html#development-environment-setup) but I'm unable to retrieve variable defined in my .env file at the root of my project. I try to load this value in my React component (`plugins/myPluginName/admin/src/containers/HomePage/index.js`).

I try with the global process module like that :

```
process.env.my_variable
```

But it returns `undefined`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @sunnyson on the [strapi forum](https://forum.strapi.io/t/use-env-in-local-plugin/992/2) I found a solution. By default .env variables are not passed to the client-side. You need to [customize webpack config](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/admin-panel/custom-webpack-config.html).

To do so :

1. Create a folder `/admin` at the root of your project then create a `admin.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, webpack) => {
    // Add your variable using the DefinePlugin function
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // ENVS that you want to use in frontend
        CUSTOM_VARIABLES: {
          variable1: JSON.stringify(process.env.variable1),
        },
      })
    );
    // Return the modified config
    return config;
  },
};
```

2. In your react component you can use your env variables like that :

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   this.state = {
   env: { CUSTOM_VARIABLES }
   }

  logEnv() {
  console.log(this.state.env.variable1)
  }

}
```

Comment: It is throwing `ReferenceError: CUSTOM_VARIABLES is not defined`. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Deleting `build` folder and rebuilding the admin panel resolve this

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the admin panel now supports dotenv variables.

Just prefix your .env variable with STRAPI_ADMIN_ and it'll be available using process.env.

For example, `STRAPI_ADMIN_KEY` in .env is available as `process.env.STRAPI_ADMIN_KEY`

Comment: You are the best! It is not mentioned in the docs that having a prefix `STRAPI_ADMIN` will expose that var to admin frontend